# Is antimatter attracted to matter by its opposite electric charge?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, antimatter, coulombs-law, matter

As it is said by many physicists that antimatter is just opposite of matter; it has opposite charge of matter, then is there is any possibility that antimatter is attracted to matter? For example - the antiparticle of the electron is the positron. Since the positron has positive charge, would it be attracted to the electron because of the electron's negative charge? **(Here I was talking about the opposite charge concept. That means the positive charge is attracted by negative charge, so why is it that all antimatter is not combined with matter to form energy all across the space?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are pretty much right. The antiparticles, such as positions,  have the opposite charge to their normal counterparts and so they will be attracted to each other. When real and anti-particles collide they will annihilate and release energy. This annihilation is not directly related to the charge and will even happen if neutral particles and antiparticles collide, e.g. (anti)neutrons.

This is why we do not observe antiparticles in everyday life, any antiparticles floating around in space will quickly annihilate with real particles.  Antimatter on Earth is primarily produced synthetically at particle accelerators which requires high energy to produce a particle, antiparticle pair.

The real question then becomes if antiparticles are always produced paired with a normal particle, why is the universe we observe primarily real matter. Where has all the rest of the antimatter gone? This is process is known as [CP-violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation), the mechanisms behind which are not currently well understood and are being investigated by the [LHCb](http://lhcb-public.web.cern.ch/lhcb-public/Welcome_270811.html) experiment at CERN.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. A particle is attracted to it's anti-particle due to the opposite charges.

The answer to your second question is that there isn't much anti-matter about to annihilation with the matter. One of the ongoing questions in physics.

It's worth you googling what happens when particles and their anti-particles annihilate. You seem not to understand that so well, judging by your final statement.